# Conditional CASCADE operation for foreign key constraint?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, foreign-keys, sql-delete

I have `parent` and `child` table where `child` has a FK pointing to the PK of parent table. When I delete something in parent table I can have child records deleted as well by having `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

However, in my `parent` table I don't delete records at all. Instead I set the column `state = "passive"`. I want to delete related entries in the `child` table.

Do we have something like a "conditional CASCADE" in Postgres? Or is the solution to manually delete entries in the `child` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do this in a trigger that takes action ON UPDATE.  Where the NEW.state = "passive", delete the child rows.

Comment: Well, Yes it was always an option to create trigger, however I was wondering if we have something like conditional cascade in Postgres Or in any RDBMS for that matter. Anyway, Thanks a lot for your response. I appreciate!

Comment: Sorry, no such animal in PostgreSQL land.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like "conditional CASCADE". The closest thing that comes to mind would be to [disable triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altertable.html). But that's not helpful in your case.

*Assumptions:*
- `state` is defined `NOT NULL`.
- `parent_id` *never* changes. If it does you'll want to cascade that UPDATE as well.

The condition to fire the trigger `ON UPDATE` should be:

```sql
     NEW.state =  "passive"
AND  OLD.state <> "passive"
```

.. since you do not want to trigger it over and over again, only once when parent is set to "passive".

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_upbef()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN

DELETE FROM child
WHERE  parent_id = OLD.parent_id;  -- OLD works for UPDATE & DELETE

RETURN NEW;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Instead of [checking the condition in the trigger function, you can do that in the trigger directly since Postgres 9.0](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html), thereby saving a bit of overhead:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER upd_cascade_del
BEFORE UPDATE ON parent
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.state =  "passive" AND
      OLD.state <> "passive")      -- parenthesis required
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_upbef();
```

Don't forget to add a trigger for `ON DELETE` as well. You don't normally DELETE, but if you do, you want to either raise an exception or cascade the operation.
Trigger function has to `RETURN OLD`, since NEW is not defined in this case. Otherwise the same:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_delbef()
...    
RETURN OLD;
...
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER del_cascade_del
BEFORE DELETE ON parent
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (OLD.state <> "passive")      -- only if not already passive
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_delbef();
```