# SQLAlchemy conditional cascade delete

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I've got a ForeignKey in my model with a cascade delete option.

Is it possible to do a conditional delete?

I would like the object to be deleted only when it's marked to be deleted.

Example:

```
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'

    can_be_deleted = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    bar = Column(
        GUID(), ForeignKey('bar.id', ondelete="CASCADE")
    )
```

So the `Foo` object should be deleted only if the `can_be_deleted` flag is set to `True` not right after the `bar` is deleted.

Comment: look if it can be done in SQL generally, seems to be [related quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336871/conditional-cascade-operation-for-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: the problem is that I'm not sure how to use it with sqlalchemy

Comment: what's the problem? writing the trigger?

Comment: yes. haven't used them with sqlalchemy before.

Comment: you can write it with raw SQL and I (or anyone else) will help you to make it work with SQLALchemy